# Find all sets of dependencies for given element

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, graph, tree

I've got a problem with finding all possible combinations of paths in java for an input like this:
Every number has list of sets of dependencies, for example number 2 depends on both 11 and 12 or there is a second possibility: both 10 and 12. Below are other examples of dependencies.
2=[[11, 12] OR [10, 12]]
1=[[9, 2, 8, 7] OR [9, 3, 8, 7] OR [2, 6, 8, 7] OR [3, 8, 7, 6]]
6=[[4] OR [5] OR [13, 10]]
22 = [[21, 13] OR  [8]]
21= [23],
11 = []
12 = []
10 = []
13 = []
9 = []
8 = []
[...]

For every number we want an output which looks like this for 22:
22: [[21,13,23], [8]],

For 1:
1: [[9, 2, 11, 12, 8, 7], 
[9, 2, 8, 7, 10, 12], 
[9, 3, 8, 7], 
[2, 6, 8, 7, 11, 12, 4], 
[2, 6, 8, 7, 10, 12, 4],
[2, 6, 8, 7, 11, 12, 5], 
[2, 6, 8, 7, 11, 12, 13, 10], 
[2, 6, 8, 7, 10, 12, 5], 
[2, 6, 8, 7, 10, 12, 13, 10],]
[3, 8, 7, 4]
[3, 8, 7, 5]
[3, 8, 7, 13, 10]]
And so on...
I tried to rewrite data to a tree and find all possible paths and second solution with recursion but I stuck. 
I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: You're stuck at what? Where is your code? What results are you getting?

Comment: Here 1 depends on two advanced nodes: 6 and2. I'm at point where I got semi-path for the node - if node depends only on one advanced node.  I dont know how recognize that there are advanced nodes. I didn't posted here the solution  because I don't think that is is a right decision to go that way. That's why I thought about nested loops and going through elements. When the advanced node is recognized - we can clone the current set and add two possible paths to each one. But I don't know what to do if we get another node with 5 advanced nodes. How to recognize which are added and which one arent

Comment: This is an application in "simple" boolean logic expressions.  You need to find all minimal input sets that will "turn on" a particular node in your data flow network.  Search symbolic logic resources for solutions to this.